# Did Joss Whedon contribute to the script for Captain America: Civil War?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, marvel, captain-america-civil-war, joss-whedon

I’m aware that [Joss Whedon didn’t have the greatest time making *Age of Ultron*](http://screencrush.com/joss-whedon-avengers-age-of-ultron-miserable-failure/), but I believe he has made [some uncredited script contributions](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Joss_Whedon) to earlier MCU movies.

While re-watching *Captain America: Civil War*, I wondered if he’d made any script contributions here too. The Vision/Scarlet Witch kitchen scene, in particular — where they

> discuss cooking, their feelings about their Infinity Stone-derived powers, and the fact that Vision actually has to keep Wanda confined to the compound for her own safety —

seemed to have a bit of Whedon-flavour to it. (It reminded me a bit of Giles and Buffy in the high school library.)

So: Are there any reports of Whedon making script contributions to *Civil War*?

Comment: Paul Bettany = Anthony Head?  We English folk aren't all the same, y'know!  ;-)

Comment: Paul Bettany = Anthony Head? We English folk aren't all the same, y'know! ;-) ;-)

Comment: Paul Bettany = Anthony Head? We English folk aren't all the same, y'know! ;-) ;-) ;-)

Comment: You guys. *You guys.* This is why this place is great.

Comment: (Also, I would pay good money to watch a spin-off cooking show entitled *Scarlet Witchin’ in the Kitchen*.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It seems unlikely.**

I haven‘t seen any reports that he had any involvement in *Civil War*, and [his comments](http://uproxx.com/gammasquad/why-joss-whedon-left-marvel/2/) on the topic sound like he’s completely done with Marvel, at least for now:

> But, I sort of had my finger in all of the films in the second phase, but then I just had to concentrate only on Ultron, and sort of know when it was done I was just going to stop. **So I made a completely clean break**, not because we had a falling out, just because I was like, “I can’t.”